# How can I create two borders or box shadows around an image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying create this background/border using only CSS but I have some difficulties:
[image: design original]

My code:

```css
.profile-userpic img {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: -10px -10px 0 0px #291026, 10px 10px 0 0px #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-userpic">
    <img src="{% get_avatar_url usuario %}" class="img-responsive " alt="">
</div>
```

Actually I got this:
[image: my work]

I need just transform the red background in a transparent object with border, just like the original design

The picture needs to be responsive and I need to use this 'border/background' in others elements like a button or div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that should help. `:before`, `:after`, and `z-index` are valuable for something like this.

CSS

```
.profile-userpic {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile-userpic:before,
.profile-userpic:after {
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.profile-userpic:before {
  background-color: red;
  top: -8px;
  left: -12px;
}

.profile-userpic:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  bottom: -25px;
  right: -25px;
}

.profile-userpic img {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d6tv5jp3/3/

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started, not responsive, but shows one way it can be accomplished.

```css
.profile-userpic img {
  transform:translateY(20px) translateX(30px);
}
.profile-userpic:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:250px;
  height:280px;
  background:black;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}
.profile-userpic:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:250px;
  height:280px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:22px;
  left:60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-userpic">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250" class="img-responsive " alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.ctn {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 
}

.picture {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
}

.picture:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  content:'';
  width: 100%;
  height: 108%;
  top:-12px;
  left:-12px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.picture:after {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid red;
  content:'';
  width: 105%;
  height: 107%;
  top:-6px;
  left:10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctn">
  
  <div class="picture"></div>
  
</div>
```

Have you considered using `:before` and `:after` elements instead:

have a look at this sample I made:

https://jsfiddle.net/bo2nn6kk/

All you need to do is position it appropriately and adjust width and height.

Comment: @Grasper My nickname back from the Black Metal guitarist days :)